# Prefered network interface of Socket.bind

Tags: java, sockets, interface, bind

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html
says "When you create the socket and bind it to that address, the system uses the associated interface". I tried to do the example on the page on Linux and Android system, however it doesn't work so on both. The bound IP address is set to source IP address on the IP header but the transmitting interface does NOT still change. Many persons referred to the URL on Stack Overflow. Does it work so really?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the interface to bind to as a hint, but the OS is free to ignore this and in fact Linux does ignore this as it has a weak hosting model. i.e. the OS determines the interface to use regardless of what you set. I would assume Android is the same.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model

Comment: What do you do if you have e.g. 2 NICs and you want to bind each of your 2 different application's interfaces on a specific NIC e.g. because one is for your connection with a remote database and the other for connection with clients?

Comment: Linux doesn't really support that. For out going packets you have no control. The best you can do for incoming connects is to give the clients a different IP address to the one the database uses.

Comment: Something I have done in the past is to have the database connected via its own network (actually one cable attached directly to the back of each machine, no switch) As this uses a separate network with different IP addresses, Linux has no choice but to use the IP addresses given.  However if Linux can find two ways to get to an IP address, you have no control over which one it uses.

Comment: But isn't this a limitation?Is this due to some kind of optimization reason?I mean does Windows do it the same way as well?

Comment: Windows XP does it the same way, this was changed in Vista and Windows 7.  The benefit is your network will reconfigure itself dynamically. e.g. you can have two cards connected to the network and if either fails it will transparently switch over. You can switch from wifi to ethernet transparently.  The problem arises when you want to control this but very few people do. You can work around this by having multiple networks which is common in larger organisations.(a single cable is all you need)

Comment: Most network adapters can handle more bandwidth than you need which is another reason using multiple cards is less common. e.g. a single 10 Gig-E or infini-band can handle more bandwidth than most machines can use.

Comment: I see what you mean.`you can have two cards connected to the network and if either fails it will transparently switch over` but if there are 2 cards available these would naturally be used over 2 different networks.I mean I don't think that for example Windows Server 2003 or 2008 (or Windows 7 Professional I guess) address end-consumer needs but enterprise needs.Am I seeing it completely wrong?

Comment: I think Linux and Windows have different ideas of what makes an enterprise system. ;)

Comment: Darn.When will they make a system that makes everyone happy :(

Comment: Like a suggested, if you really want more bandwidth, cable your server directly to your database, or even better put your database on your server. ;)

Comment: Putting the database on the server is a bad idea IMO unless you have really strong hardware (or trivial data). Cabling the server directly to the database is a good idea provided that you keep everything co-located.But the rest were interesting to know.Than you!

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I have been studying host model of android OS. It implements weak host model and [RFC6419](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6419#page-11)said "The Android reference documentation describes the android.net package and the ConnectivityManager class that applications can use to request the first hop to a specified destination address via a
specified network interface. However I could not find a API for it in ConnectivityManager.